# Show related products on category view - Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, category, related-products

Is it possible to call out the related products on category pages? So within each product in the grid, it would also display the full list of that product's related products.

[image: Related products on category]

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code on your phtml file.

```
$product_id = '1';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$relatedProducts = $product->getRelatedProducts();

//var_dump($relatedProducts);

if (!empty($relatedProducts)) {
    echo 'Related Products <br />';   
    foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {
        $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($relatedProduct->getId());
        echo $relatedProduct->getId().'<br/>';
        echo $_product->getPrice().'<br/>';
        echo $_product->getName().'<br/>';
        echo $relatedProduct->getId(); //get name
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a complete solution - it lists products related to another product - not to the category like in the question